# Get connection string by environment in ConfigureServices

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, environment-variables, connection-string

I have 3 connection strings. Default is for EF Core migration management, Container is for development with docker.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=Identity;User Id=sa;Password=yourStrong(!)Password",
    "Container": "Server=identity_db,1433;Database=Identity;User Id=sa;Password=yourStrong(!)Password",
    "Production": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=Identity;User Id=sa;Password=yourStrong(!)Password"
  }
}
```

I'm adding a DbContext in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
});
```

How do i get a connectiong string based on environment? Ie. get "Default" in case of `IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment == true`?

Comment: You can inject the `IHostingEnvironment` into the Startup constructor or you can use per environment configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=basicconfiguration#configuration-by-environment

Comment: you shouldn't put all your connectionstrings in the same file.  You should use the features provided by dotnet core: appsettings.<environment>.json